Wrap an array around an object without a curve
I have an array of cones I am trying to wrap around another object like in the reference photo:

When I am trying to use the array modifier's "Object Offset" all cones are thrown randomly all over.
When I try to add a shrink-wrap modifier it just flattens out the cones into circles.
I also tried revolving the array using the Curve modifier but am getting this weird result:

Is there a way to wrap around the object the cones like in the picture without adding a new curve from scratch?
Original Blender File

A solution, but with a curve: Let's imagine that this is the neck of your character, use the knife to cut the shape of the necklace (K to activate, C to cut through):

Duplicate the edge loop you've just created, separate it as a new object (P) then in Object mode select the new object and convert to curve. Now use this curve as Curve modifier target for the pearl object:


I tried implementing your solution but got some weird results, I edited my question to show how it ended up like. Am I doing something wrong in the process?

Could you please share your file?

Yes, I edited the original post and added a link to the file at its ends

You need to put the curve and the object at the same location: first select the curve, right click > Set Origin > Origin to Geometry, then Shift S > Cursor to selected, then select the object and Shift S > Selection to Cursor. If it's not correctly oriented, select it, switch to Edit mode and rotate it 180°
